# Converting a numeric value to time in R

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

I have a vector of numeric values and need to convert these back into date and time.

```
dput(vector)

c(1547224631587, 1547224162579, 1547224161576, 1547224160582, 
1547224159591, 1547224158590, 1547224157574, 1547224156571, 1547224155584, 
1547224154572)
```

This is Unix time stamp converted into milliseconds. I have tried using `POSIXlt` & `POSIXct` but the year it comes up with is 2019. Do I need to get an idea of when the time is from?

I have tried as.Data(as.POSIXct(x/1e3,origin="1970-01-01")) but it gives out the day, month and year only which is correct but does not provide the time in hours:minutes:seconds.

Am I missing something or anyone know of a different way of getting the date as well as time using a different function?

Comment: What's the origin and the time zone? Also, if these are milliseconds, you'll probably need divide by 1e3, because `as.POSIXct` works with seconds. Here's an example `as.POSIXct(vector/1e3, origin = "1900-01-01")`

Comment: I have found out that the year is 2015 and the month is between October - December with time zone is GMT.